# Select count return 0 mysql JDBC

Tags: mysql, select, jdbc, count, procedures

I'm trying to store messages, so i create 2 tables in mysql with HeidiSql, the first one is msg and the second one is users. I wrote a store procedure to get the number of messages that have as sender the first parameter, as recipient the second parameter and viceversa, i stored this value in id variable. I need the variable to count the messages between 2 people. When i run the application from java, i always get id=0. I can't understand the mistake.

```
...

sql="call getIdMsg(?,?,?)";
sql2="call addRecord(?,?,?,?)";

try (Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection(db_url,username,password);
         CallableStatement statement = conn.prepareCall(sql);
         CallableStatement statement2 = conn.prepareCall(sql2)){

        statement.setInt(1,sender);
        System.out.println(sender);
        statement.setInt(2,recipient);
        System.out.println(recipient);
        statement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
        statement.execute();
        id=statement.getInt(3);

        System.out.println("ID is: "+id);

        statement2.setInt(1,sender);
        statement2.setInt(2,recipient);
        statement2.setInt(3,id);
        statement2.setString(4,msg);
        statement2.execute();
        System.out.println("The record is been added");
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle){sqle.printStackTrace();}
...
```

This is my sql code:

```
BEGIN
set @id = ((select count(*) from msg WHERE sender = @thisrecipient and recipient = @thissender)+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM msg WHERE sender = @thissender and recipient = @thisrecipient));
END
```

These are my parameters:

1. thissender INT IN
2. thisrecipient INT IN
3. id INT OUT

Could you help me please?

Comment: maybe before "id=statement.getInt(3);" you have to get some resultSet and call next() for it

Comment: Thank you, i fixed it. I use a prepared statement and i pass this string as parameter: "select count(id) from msg where sender=? and recipient = ?" (i obviously set the value of ? with preparedstatement.setInt(int index)), then i use a resultset to store the query i get, i call resultset.next() and resultset.getInt(1).

Comment: If your procedure out is a cursor, you can assign it a resultset I guess